# Does inotify group IN_MOVED_FROM and IN_MOVED_TO?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, inotify

I'm using a single inotify file descriptor to monitor many busy directories for several events, including `IN_MOVED_TO` and `IN_MOVED_FROM`.

I have a loop that calls `read` on it (which blocks until there is data to be read) and handles events as they happen.

When a file is moved between two of the directories being monitored, two `inotify_event`s are written to the inotify file descriptor: one with the `IN_MOVED_TO` bit set in `mask` and one with `IN_MOVED_FROM`, both with the same `cookie`.

Is it guaranteed that both events will be buffered with the same call to `read`, or might I need to call it once to buffer one event and again to buffer the next?

Comment: It seems to be that there can't be any such guarantee: what if your read buffer is not big enough to contain both events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there isn't such a gurantee.
What we can rely on is only the fact that the two events(`IN_MOVED_FROM`, `IN_MOVED_TO`) on a rename operation are assocaited with the same `cookie`.

Any assumption except above is unreliable, for instance:

- The two events will come sequentially(one comes right after the other).
- The two events will be appear in the same `read` system call together.